# Is stackexchange a good place for questions

Tags: discussion

It should be, in theory it should be. But it isn't, and I don't think it's just a gap in in expertise. On my last question, which when you google the terms of throws up quite a few OUP book chapters, ones which alas I cannot access, I was told that my question wasn't about philosophy unless I had a quote. Can you imagine how stupid the world would be if that were the case? I was confused about how to do long division so now I'm a "philosopher".

Do we really have to engage in deep thinking to work out what questions are answerable, clear and about philosophy?

All I mean is that the site is *not* a good resource for asking questions that you cannot find the answer for. Maybe just me? Quite what role it is fulfilling for anyone is beyond me.

Comment: It is _helpful_ to ground questions in a text since that provides significant context and philosophical motivation, not to mention some useful common ground for discussion. Certainly not _required_ if sufficient context and motivation is otherwise provided but textual evidence is a baseline in the discipline for demonstrating a minimum of research…

Comment: not required but a baseline @JosephWeissman wth are you trying to say? you seem to think se is something it isn't

Comment: don't bother explaining, just parrot something that everyone already knows and doesn't answer the question @JosephWeissman why should meta be any better?

Comment: I appreciate your confidence in our abilities! But there are definitely many questions that may sound philosophical but aren’t sufficiently grounded to be answered on SE. You might find it worthwhile to review some of the discussion here on meta around the on-topic line — why we tend to ask not only for clarification but the specific context in which your philosophical problem arises. An older post but may still be helpful to new users trying to understand how we landed on this compromise — https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes you need to provide a quote to convince people that you belong on this site, which is very academic.