# Why does it seem that the philosophy of Atheism is the sieve by which all questions must be filtered?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, questions

The Philosophy SE site allows users to make egregious and outlandish statements about Theism (and Christianity) and allows proponents of Atheistic philosophies (Atheism. Naturalism, Secularism, etc.) to be vocal about their beliefs. The "pushing" of these ideologies is allowed.

But when questions are submitted that expose the flaws of the fundamentals of Atheism, they are quickly "closed."  Any exposing of the unreasonableness of the Atheistic philosophy is not allowed! For example questions like: *What is the Source of morality in Atheism.....Is Atheism based on fact, hypothesis or opinion?.....What has been the effect of Atheism on societies and governments.....Is Atheism scientific if it is not falsifiable...How does Atheism deal with the Problem of Good...etc.*

It seems that Atheism has a stranglehold on the Site and won't let its philosophy be analyzed, scrutinized...or exposed in broad daylight.  Exposing its flaws is not allowed. Questions, or answers, that venture onto this minefield are censored by (1) drastic editing, (2) closing, (3) hiding comments, (4) screening the type-setting (fading), (5) accusing of "pushing a personal philosophy, (6) not dealing with a topic of philosophy (off-topic), (7) down-voting, not because of the quality of the question, but by prejudice, (8) redacting history of Atheism, (9) letting the G-- word disqualify the posting, and (10) labeling.

It is admitted that the exposing of flaws in one's worldview philosophy can be a traumatic experience, but can that trump free speech?  Progress is predicated upon the open flow of information so people can make **informed decisions**. Isn't this what StackExchange is all about? Free exchange of ideas, and allowing everybody at the conference table? Isn't this is what America is about? (Remember the 4 Freedoms of F.D.R.?)

The Help Center lists the following **on topic** subjects:

1. epistemology-e.g. Is there a scientific method that verifies atheism, or is it just an opinion?
2. Ethics -e.g. What is the Source of Ethics (right and wrong) that Atheism appeals to; and is it valid?
3. Metaphysics-Does a supernatural solution to a question about a Naturalistic philosophy invalidate the question?
4. Logic-Are valid syllogisms with true premises disqualified simply because they disprove naturalistic philosophies (Atheism, secularism, naturalism, humanism)?
5. Aesthetics-Does aesthetics, and consciousness itself, require more than a naturalistic cause for an explanation of its existence?
6. History of philosophy,(Domains and personalities associated with philosophy)-What were the reasons persons gave for adopting Atheism, and how did it affect their conduct in society, family, government?
7. Applied Philosophy-What was the philosophical inspiration for the French Revolution? What happens to a society when an Atheistic philosophy pervades a government?

However on PhilosophySE when these types of questions are broached, and they prove embarrassing to the Naturalistic Philosophies, revealing inherent, fatal flaws, the questions are closed, deleted, etc.  And instead of dealing with appropriate Answers to the Question, the questioner's character is assailed--As Is Evident By the Comments Given Below!

Just answer the Questions of the User!  If another site user finds the Question too hard to handle, just move on, or put it on the shelf of his mind and mull over it for a while until a rational answer can be achieved.  But refuge tactics, defense mechanisms, reactive emotings, do not enhance the credibility of the Philosophy site. The "pushing of one's naturalistic philosophy" at the expense of others doesn't seem to be advancing progress rationally. Intolerance of dissent is not becoming in academia in a free society.

Syllogisms based on impeccable logic, historical facts, deductive reasoning, empirical methodology, and scientific laws, as well as "self-evident truths" should rule the day...no matter how unpleasant the outcome to one's philosophical worldview.

Comment: Can you link to any examples of the problem that you see..?

Comment: That may be your impression. My impression is different. I regularly get flags that claim "rude or abusive" on posts that express an atheistic viewpoint simply for that reason, whereas I rarely get the same on posts that express theist viewpoints.

Comment: I'm contemplating writing an answer to this question, but as @JosephWeissman points out, it is *very difficult* to discuss this in detail without at least one or two examples. But to briefly summarize what I might otherwise write out in full, Stack Exchange is *not* "all about" free speech. It is about questions and answers. Anything that [doesn't fit into the site's purpose](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) may be closed and/or deleted, and this is very much by design. In short: Stack Exchange is not a forum.

Comment: I will say the same thing here as I did in the Islam thread - weaponised argumentation is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Paul Ross-"Weaponized argumentation" is an inappropriate phrase for describing genuine inquiry into the reasoning and rationale of a philosophy, even if it uncovers a flaw in that philosophy that causes its adherents cause to pause.

Comment: @raygrant It would be, wouldn't it? Nonetheless I stand by my use of it in description of your questions.

Comment: @PaulRoss "What is the Source of morality in Atheism?" Could you rephrase this question so it isn't a "weaponized argumentation?  "Is Atheism baed on Fact, Hypothesis, or Opinion?" Could you rephrase this so it isn't a "weaponized argumentation?  "Ia Atheism scientific if it is not falsifiable?" Could you rephrase this also, so it is not a weaponized argumentation?---Or are these not legitimate insightful examinations into the philosophy of Atheism?

Comment: @raygrant, let's take this seriously.  Yes, I can, and I think there are interesting such versions of those questions.  However, you have persistently and clearly presented your questions in such a way as indicates you have absolutely no interest in doing so in good faith.  "Are atheists aware of the consequences of adopting the philosophy of Evolution as a social ethic?", "Since the philosophy of atheism is declared by atheists to be "a belief in nothing, a belief of nothing...then it makes no factual statements!", "there is no doubt abut Jesus walking down the cobblestone roads of Jerusalem"

Comment: @raygrant, hopefully what is clear is that I am directly accusing *you* of weilding arguments as weapons, and there is no place for that here.  One can quite reasonably engage in these discussions without doing so.  You have not, and your questions have thus, correctly, been downvoted and closed.

Comment: @Paul Ross. I understand and emphasize with you that penetrating logical deductions that expose weakness in a philosophy may seem like "weapons" but others would consider them linguistic tools of the trade that lead to truth statements  that satisfy the inquiring mind.

Comment: @raygrant, a bottle in some contexts is just a tool to hold fluids. When smashed against a table and directed at someone, it is a weapon. I am saying to you that you have no intention to engage in philosophy- your purpose is to harass, and so you are weaponising argumentation. There is nothing else to be said.

Comment: @Paul Ross. Simply "answer" the questions. Consider the logical deductions of the Valid Syllogisms provided.  Respond to the application of the definition of the Empirical Method of Science to Atheism. Check the History of Applied Philosophy as it applies to Atheism. Explore the Epistemological approaches of Atheism.   Don't avoid dealing with the important issues raised (all of which are listed as on-topic in Helps Center) by substituting it with mischaracterizing  the boldness of the questioner. Show a philosophical answer to the questions, and academia will be advanced.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between most (there are many rightfully closed ones as well) questions on atheist positions and the questions you name is simple:

While these questions are *actual questions asked in good faith (pun intended) and out of curiosity*, you indeed tend to push a personal belief and never really *question* the outcome, as evidenced by your comments that are borderline proselytising (and I'm being kind with adding "borderline" here).

And that is the general problem: We do not need to take care of some properly weighed representation of beliefs here. Belief is for the churches. We have to take care that there are actual questions that are answerable on the basis of existing philosophical work and expertise knowledge about them, not faith or opinion.

Comment: Klocking-The question listed in the above query are not asking for opinions or faith statements but factual answers. And when '

Comment: Knocking-The questions listed in the above query are not asking for opinions or faith statements but factual answers. And when the answers, or failure to adequately answer,  leads to valid deductions that tend toward a metaphysical conclusion, which make the adherent uncomfortable, it still would be inappropriate to resort to "closure, deletion, etc." Helps Center listings include metaphysics topics! To close would be an example of  intolerance and suppression of speech, would it not?

Comment: @raygrant You seem to think that just because there are other positions, they have an equal right to be represented here. That is not the case. Philosophy and argumentation are not a matter of opinion (or faith). The fallacies and shortcomings of ontological arguments for the existence of an Abrahamic God have been found, pointed out, and discussed time and again (for at least 300 years!), including on this site. And "but the existence of God is evident!" is not by itself an argument, it is a statement (of faith) that, if used in or as an argument, needs argumentative support.

Comment: KlockingI I agree wholeheartedly that argumentation needs logical proof, and not simply faith statements...so what's your point? Syllogisms based on true premises and with valid deductions are legitimate.  These are not to be considered "faith statements" simply because they do not conform to a prevalent  or popular worldview.

Comment: @raygrant You never *actually asked* something, you presented arguments you thought were "based on true arguments and with valid deductions" and attacked everyone who pointed out that this is not what *questions* are for. Also, you completely ignore the immense body of philosophical works that show the logical gaps and problems with your arguments. The latter is not even the problem, though. This is not about the content, at all. It is about posts that try to present, push, and defend an argument and are, therefore, not questions posed in good faith.

Answer (score 2):

After almost 4 years of participation, I'll share with you my thoughts.

Once or twice a year, a [true believer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_True_Believer) comes to this site, not equipped to engage in general philosophical discourse, but starts spurting language to proselytize or condemn the outright lack of theological tolerance. It is one of the primary strengths of philosophy that it encourages skepticism and fallibilism and largely eschews [fideism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fideism). Thus, what you tend to find as a population here are people equipped with critical thinking and inoculated against indoctrination and it's rhetorical techniques.

On the whole, as an absurdist, I absolutely encourage theological discussion here through the lens of a non-believer. Christianity SE is the place to go to find people who presume certain [metaphysical necessities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysical_necessity) that I and other atheists are free to question. You're free to question my metaphysical presuppositions, and I'm free to question yours. You can even unleash the standard rhetorical techniques, because it's just admission the basic epistemology that you rest your case on is underdeveloped; I'll call you out on every appeal to emotion, authority, and popularity you can muster.

What counts here is the language of formal and informal logic, and so you shouldn't be surprised that if you enter a forum where people discuss topics like bounded rationality, the philosophy of religion, and semiotics, you might be ill-prepared to hold your end up considering you've been exposed to religious catechism which is generally applied to children long before they have the capacity to resist it, and often far longer when it has driven out those who have strongly skeptical intuitions.

There is no holy book that is holy here, because this is not a church. It's a community of people who are interested and experts in logic and argumentation, formal and informal, and command a wide reading of the greatest books in history, often whatever flavor of religious good book they grew up in contact with (me, the Book of Concord).

As long as you don't go around declaring people to be pagans who will be punished, and don't mind being met with sarcasm when your standard rhetorical techniques fall flat on your face (philosophers are far better thinkers than average folks), then you're welcome. If you want someone to agree with you, pick your whatever of the thousands of gods that are worshiped, and go find some true believers. But you'll likely get little in the way of traction here through emotional manipulation and logical fallacy. This is a forum that welcomes theological analysis, but does not presume it. There's are plenty of forums for theology, so if you don't like it, move on.

Comment: Of course, there are a lot of knee-jerk "religion-bad" folks here who just downvote without regard to your philosophical sophistication. But they downvote anything they don't understand, so c'est la vie. That makes a nice seque into Plato's views on philosopher kings who...

Comment: @JDThe answer you gave above is a red herring rant. The questions posed on PSE were non-religious, and required a straight-forward answer about the philosophy at hand. If the logical deductions proved embarrassing or uncomfortable to the adherent, or exposed a vital flaw in its rationale...and if they lead to a metaphysical   solution, that does not automatically disqualify the question...according to Helps Center listing! Go back and read them,  it is strongly suggested.  To "close" or "delete" would be a sign of atheistic intolerance and suppression.  Peace.

Comment: @raygrant "It seems that Atheism has a stranglehold on the Site and won't let its philosophy be analyzed, scrutinized...or exposed in broad daylight." This is a feeble , loaded statement that has no bearing on reality. "when questions are submitted that expose the flaws of the fundamentals of Atheism, they are quickly "closed." Any exposing of the unreasonableness of the Atheistic philosophy is not allowed!" This seems drivel seems an echo of the sort of persecution complex messianic religions peddle.

Comment: In fairness to you, since you may have been inculcated into whatever flavor of religion you believe in before adulthood when the brain is fully developed, in rhetoric, [loaded language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_language) is a cheap appeal to emotion. "exposing the unreasonableness of atheism", "exposing atheism to broad daylight", and "the embarrassing deductions of atheism" are all loaded language that presume the conclusion. While it's true the majority of professional philosophers aren't committed to a religion (or even any supernatural beings), when you show up to shout...

Comment: "atheism is unreasonable, poorly reasoned, and should be an embarrassment to the utterer", you're bound to get pushback. I reviewed your question and part of the problem is that it doesn't orient itself to the Q&A format. If you're here to "drive the illogic of athiesm out of the darkness into the light" you'd be better off at https://thephilosophyforum.com/.

Comment: Read the HelpCenter that deals with Answering one's own Question and you will see that it is encouraged!  Because Atheists or friends of atheists don't agree with the Answer is no reason to deny one the privilege of answering, scrutinizing, exposing, analyzing, or otherwise exploring its accuracy.

Comment: @raygrant Yes. That I concede. But the point is to ask a research-like, clarificatory, or logic-suspect question to elicit a canonically supported, language-clarifying, or logic-analyzed response. That's what is meant by Q&A. The goal is to introduce a measure of objectivity by providing a certain standard to discourse. This isn't the agorra. It's more like a place where research-minded folk hang out to get pointers or explanations. There's a difference between truth and satisfaction or adequacy. This forum is pluralistic in that it accepts as a fundamental premise that truth and discourse...

Comment: are naturally open to a variety of interpretations. As long as the question and the answer are commensurate with the spirit of investigation, that is argumenation-as-exploration, then no problems. This is a place to investigate philosophy, not to conduct philosophical investigation, though, as always, I maintain there is no crisp line in such an endeavor.

Answer (score -3):

Moderators:  Check question #98128 where the questioner is accused of "pushing a personal philosophy.  Then look at the comment of David Gudeman, who pretty much agrees with my complaint! Asking about another philosophy's aspect (belief) is in no way "pushing a personal philosophy".

Notice also that an edit by Futilitarian changed the wording in the explanation after the question of "God" to "god" (lower case) and "Him" to "it"...which totally changed the meaning of the question posed.  A lower case god would not be sufficient to resolve the Atheistic philosophy issue.  And to call Him an "it" many would call blasphemy (at least, offensive).

Comment: If I be accused of "pushing my own personal philosophy"--whatever my philosophy is--then does that mean I am now a PHILOSOPHER?  An unexpected honor, to say the least! (Please tell me what my philosophy is, by the way.)

Comment: The atheist can well be questioning the existence of any god. For the atheist, the Christian (and Jewish, and Muslim) belief in a single God can be absolutely meaningless. Atheism is not *necessarily* doubting the One. It is about doubting anything that counts as god. MONOtheism (belief in a single God), POLYtheism (belief in several gods), and Atheism (belief in no god(s)) are three descriptive Greek terms without any *a priori* preference. Hence, the edit made perfect sense. Calling everyone who does not share the same belief blasphemic is pretty medieval, btw.

Comment: @Philip KlockingWe are aware of the several definitions of "atheism" ( See Wikipedia).  Our contention is that just as every other ideology, philosophy, or God forbid, religion, is legitimately open to examination, scrutiny, evaluation, or exposing, so are the Naturalistic positions (Atheism, secularism, naturalism, materialism, humanism).  To shut down inquiry about them--and allow criticism of supernatural philosophies (Theism, deism, polytheism)--is unscholarly, as well as unfair. Atheism certainly should not be the default mechanism for Philosophy, or "closure" be the refuge strategy.

Comment: "Atheism certainly should not be the default mechanism for Philosophy, or 'closure' be the refuge strategy." It's not, and your claims otherwise are anecdotal. There are plenty of theology questions on this forum. Start here with the theology tag https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theology

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=good-and-evil 1233 posts

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-religion 508 posts

Comment: "Would God showing up disprove atheism" - That's a ridiculously poor quality of question. Of course it would, presuming of course any god arrived on a chariot of fire followed by a portal in the sky where hosts of heavenly angels armed with tridents flew around smiting the wicked. So, by asking a question that answers itself, you're really making a statement. This is called a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question).

Comment: You seem to lack the fundamentals. I would start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentation_theory

Comment: @JD Are not rhetorical questions used to instigate investigation into the legitimacy of particular ideologies?  To inspire examination into 'taken for granted' ideas that need scrutiny and reevaluation? To reassure the validity of any philosophical applications?

Comment: @raygrant You have it the wrong way around. The arguments you want to be acknowledged and heard are those that have been taken for granted over hundreds of years, not least because those who did scrutinise them critically had been sacked from their posts or banished from their cities just because it went against "popular worldview". *The (Roman Catholic) church* did hinder the development of philosophy out of ideological reasons. The things you claim here as "taken for granted" are the outcome of the emancipation of philosophy of the last ~150-200 years.

Comment: @raygrant Absolutely, but this is not a form to practice rhetoric; it's a forum to ask literal questions, and get well-developed answers with citations from canons. Thus, an argumentative rhetorical question should be closed because it's outside the scope of this site's aim. Now, there's the question of where the demarcation lies, which is an objection I myself have raised. https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers Is a pivotal post in this discussion.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to pursue philosophy in the form of theology if its right for you, but the traditional presumptions of theology are not givens here. They can only arise from contemporary notions of metaphysical explanation which is often secular, but technically neutral in the regards to the existence of the supernatural. You come with supernatural claims, so be it. But that you use rhetorical pathos instead of anchor your questions and responses in canonical references and non-idiosyncratic language is a non-grata of this forum, not just because it's a secular forum...

Comment: and not just because SE Christianity is provided as an alternative, but because the primary aim is to disseminate and explicate on established philosophical topics with the tools of all contemporary philosophical traditions, though obviously the Eastern philosophies tend to be underrepresented, and the Anglo-American tradition over-represented. This is place is quite the mix of beginners and experts, believers and non-believers, and people of vastly varying degrees of the capacity to exercise self-insight... you're more than welcome to pursue theological questions AS canon-referential Q&A.

Comment: Don't be a flash in the pan and stick around and contribute. Stick to your beliefs. Just learn the written and unwritten rules of more professional philosophical discourse, and reflect on to what extent your axiological presumptions are driven by deeper psychological needs. You want to develop a doctrine to rebut [non-cognitive emotivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotivism), this is the place to ask questions and get somewhat, sometimes quality responses. (You get what you pay for, of course.)

Comment: @JD. Ought not Atheism advocates also "reflect on to what extent their axiological presumptions are driven by deeper psychological needs" if indeed this is a legitimate topic.  I recently heard, for clarification of this, one scholar quip, "Atheists  deep down, know there is a God, they just don't want to serve him!"  But back to the real issue, Atheists flaunt their belief by proudly displaying the NO GOD moniker (Gk. a+theos) . But they object vehemently when a person should mention a YES GOD  position, and label it "pushing one's personal philosophy," worthy of "closure, deletion, etc.".

Comment: @JD. Thank you for bringing up the idea of "rhetorical pathos" and "presumptions."  All philosophical scholars admit that each philosopher comes to the table with Presumptions!  t

Comment: @JD. (I hit wrong button before finishing comment.). However, "rhetorical pathos" is an unwarranted nomenclature.  LOGICAL SYLLOGISMS were employed.  SCIENTIFIC METHODOLOGY was applied to Atheism definitions.  EPISTEMOLOGY  was broached.  These are not idiosyncratic verbage,  but valid methods of inquiry.  One would probably suppose that use of derogatory language (rhetorical pathos, etc.) is merely a refuge tactic to avoid  answering the questions straight on.

Comment: @raygrant 'Ought not Atheism advocates also "reflect on to what extent their axiological presumptions are driven by deeper psychological needs" if indeed this is a legitimate topic.' Yes, and we routine do with a naturalistic epistemology. I for one reduce the logical to psychological heavily particularly in line with the notion that consciousness is a series of cognitive representations grounded in neural computation. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness-neuroscience/

Comment: "Atheists flaunt their belief by proudly displaying the NO GOD moniker (Gk. a+theos) . But they object vehemently when a person should mention a YES GOD position" One of the things we do around here is draw finder distinctions. Thus, some atheists, some theists. I live quite in harmony with believers as I was raised and confirmed in church. Most believers and non-believers get by everyday with tolerance and affection. The picture you paint is when rabble from both sides engage in needlessly and emotionally driven disputation.

Comment: " One would probably suppose that use of derogatory language (rhetorical pathos, etc.) is merely a refuge tactic to avoid answering the questions straight on." There are some who say there four types of argumentation that range from mutual exploration (zetetic method) to combative attempts at persuasion of others (debate). Then there's argumentation as bickering which is usually some form of a speech act to virtue signal or to use aggression as a coping mechanism. Usually people in the latter category are often known for splitting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_(psychology)

Comment: Everyone should ask themselves, what does my behavior get me? From Christianity, one can explore compassion, for non-believers, one can explore psychological altruism. Philosophy is just a language-game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_game_(philosophy)